# using moment.js with Meteor to write days / hours / months past

Tags: meteor, momentjs

I'm using http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/ in a Meteor project...
(package: https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/moment)

I want to write out something like

- "User: jsmith  **joined 4 years ago**"

I must be missing a conversion from mongoDB dates to moment?

json object mongo

```
{
"_id" : "vWM5Sg67fqxQAzrnv",
"createdAt" : ISODate("2015-03-14T03:39:03.384Z"),
"emails" : [
{... etc.
```

When I type this into console

```
Meteor.user().createdAt;
```

returns

```
Mon Mar 16 2015 14:11:54 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

In my test.js file
this works

```
var d= new Date('2011-04-11')
var dd= moment(d).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
console.log (dd);  // returns 04/10/2011
```

this works

```
var dd  = moment([1954, 5, 8]).fromNow(true); // 4 years
console.log (dd);
```

returns 61 years

```
this **DOESN'T** work

d = Meteor.user().createdAt;
var dd= moment([d]).fromNow(true);
console.log (dd);
```

returns TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 
Meteor.user().createdAt')

**Any help would be appreciated, been trying a while..**

Note: in my template

```
{{currentUser.createdAt}}
```

does works (i.e. been published)

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a race condition where the user hasn't logged in when your code executes. A good way to solve this is just to create a helper which will rerun when the user is logged in. However, in this case I think adding a generic helper for moment time stamps may be more appropriate:

```js
Template.registerHelper('fromNow', function(date) {
  if (date)
    return moment(date).fromNow(true);
});
```

Then in your template you can do this:

```
{{fromNow currentUser.createdAt}}
```

Because `currentUser` is reactive, this should do the right thing. Also note that `moment([d])` isn't right because in this example `d` is a `Date` object (not an array literal like your previous example).

Comment: It works!  I added `<small>Joined</small>:{{fromNow currentUser.createdAt}}
<br>
<small>Updated</small>:{{fromNow currentUser.updatedAt}}` - I had to add my Simple Schema - wonder why they don't include updatedAt in Meteor? you saved me a lot of time. **Thanks!** - that moment.js is a great package too... I always find date manipulation difficult.